# SSIS - Derived Column Calculation Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

having a few issues with a calculation in a derived column in SSIS.

I am trying to perform the following calculation -

```
4206 + ((4206 * 4206) * 0.000150000000000) + ((4206 * 4206 * 4206) * 0.000000010000000)
```

I am getting an error of -

```
**The magnitude of the result of a binary operation overflows the maximum size for result data type**
```

Pasting this calculation into my C# Web application caused a similar issue -

```
**The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode**
```

It was complaining about this section - `4206 * 4206 * 4206`.
It can be resolved in the web application by changing it too `4206 * 4206 * 4206L`, but I have no idea how to resolve this in the SSIS package.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Overflow exception now resolved, however the old and new calculations are returning slightly different values, e.g. using 415 as the input value instead of 4206 -

Old calculated value = 419.014582
New calculated value = 419.042100

The exact calculation is -

Old - `InputValue + ((InputValue * InputValue) * (DT_DECIMAL,20)@[User::SquaredValue]) + ((InputValue * InputValue * InputValue) * (DT_DECIMAL,20)@[User::CubicValue])`

New - `InputValue + (((DT_DECIMAL,20)@[User::SquaredValue] * InputValue * InputValue)) + (((DT_DECIMAL,20)@[User::CubicValue] * InputValue * InputValue * InputValue))`

**EDIT**

2nd issue around slight differences in the calculation opened as a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just change

```
((4206 * 4206 * 4206) * 0.000000010000000)
```

to

```
(0.000000010000000 * 4206 * 4206 * 4206)
```

to avoid such big numbers in the internal row calculation. I'd use

```
4206 + (0.00015 * 4206 * 4206) + (0.00000001 * 4206 * 4206 * 4206)
```

Comment: Hmm, after further investigation this is still not quite right, the error has gone, but the new calculation returns a slightly different value to the old one... See edit in original question.

Comment: @user1948635: Minimal differences in the result can come from floating point inaccuracies

Comment: I have put the actual calculations above (direct from the derived column component), can you see what would cause it? When running with manually input numbers instead of the variables above the calculations match so I assume it is a cast.

Comment: Actually, my last comment is not quite right, the 2 calculations (even when writing as 415 * ...) come out slightly different

Comment: @user1948635: BTW when using decimal for all values then even this works: `select 4206.0 + ((4206.0 * 4206.0) * 0.00015) + ((4206.0 * 4206.0 * 4206.0) * 0.00000001)`

Comment: @user1948635: But mathematically both formulas are the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38726/discussion-between-user1948635-and-juergen-d)